# Take mongdb dump from amazon awz from local

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am trying to take a mongodb dump from amazon aws server. 
Kinldy share the command

From Local it is working

```
sudo mongodump -d db** -o /opt/backup/
```

How to do it from server

```
sudo mongodump -d db** -i /opt/x.pem ubuntu@ip:/
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you need to do in order to make sure remote mongodump is possible -

1. Make sure the security group allows for communications between your
   computer and port 27017 (or any other port mongo is running on your
   server)
2. Check if mongodb is configured to bind a specific IP (by default it
   is binded to 127.0.0.1 which allows for local communications only)
3. Change your mongodump command to something like this -  `mongodump
   -d <db**> -u <username> -p <password> --host <server_ip/dns>`

Having said that, it is often better to ssh into the server and dump the data locally, then zip it and copy it to your local machine in order to minimize network load. If you have ssh access to the server this would be a much better (and more secure) approach for dumping your data.